# How do I update all records, that met the requirements except id N?

Tags: mysql

Here is my sample data:

```
id    name    age    location    staff     score
-------------------------------------------------
1     Joe     21     uk          0         100
2     Sam     27     uk          0         200
3     Luke    21     uk          1         3000
4     Kim     25     usa         0         60
```

I want to reset the score back to say `10`, for all, except Luke on id `3`, without resetting Luke back to `0`.

I'd code it like this:

```
UPDATE users_stats SET score = '10' WHERE staff = '0' AND not(id = '3')
```

But that resets id `3` to `0`. I don't want it touching the id `3`.

Comment: LGTM could be that your column types are ints and you are checking value against a varchar (' ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is like this:

```
UPDATE users_stats 
   SET score = 10
 WHERE staff = 0 AND 
       id <> 3
```

A more common way would be:

```
UPDATE users_stats 
   SET score = 10
 WHERE staff = 0 AND 
       id != 3
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccd63/1)

In MySQL they both mean the same thing:

- If id is different than 3

Also just as a side note, since Luke is a staff `1` you don't even need the `id` check as it will only change the score of those with staff `0` to score `10`.

Comment: yeah I realized that as I was looking back on myself. Thanks alot.